# Assignment of an operation without intermediate object

Tags: c++

Given a class like this:

```
class Vec{
  int comp[2];
public:
  void add(Vec& vec, Vec& vec2){
    comp[0] = vec.comp[0] + vec2.comp[0];
    comp[1] = vec.comp[1] + vec2.comp[1];
  }
  Vec operator+ (Vec& vec){
    Vec res;
    res.comp[0] = comp[0] + vec.comp[0];
    res.comp[1] = comp[1] + vec.comp[1];
    return res;
  }
};
```

There are two member functions that essentially do the same thing, which is add two `Vec`s together. The difference, of course, is that there are no intermediate values involved in the `add` function, whereas `operator+` declares a local object of `Vec`.

My question is, is there any way to define `operator+` in combination with `operator=` to have the same semantics as `add`, having no intermediate values? The rationale is to decrease the amount of intermediate values involved, for efficiency, yet keep the elegance of the `operator` syntax.

The C++ interface for the GMP library apparently is able to do this: http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-General

> An important feature of the implementation is that an expression like a=b+c results in a single call to the corresponding mpz_add, without using a temporary for the b+c part.

I'm wondering if there is some possible way to do this, or would GMP have to use some sort of workaround for this?

Comment: They use expression templates. Have a look at the code: http://hg.gmplib.org:8000/gmp/file/a47cb5fc9aab/gmpxx.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea, because it violates the natural assumptions most people have about the behavior of operators.

Unfortunately it is also very important (especially for libraries like `gmpxx`, which want to offer natural code using operators, high performance, and have huge objects as arguments). How do they achieve this? By using expression templates they can optimize expression at compile time. The idea is that operators don't return values directly but concrete instances of expression classes which then can be manipulated with meta-programming.

Expression templates are an rather advanced topic and you should be relatively certain that it will give a significant benefit to your code. In your example the size of the vectors simply isn't relevant enough.

[Wiki Expression Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

Answer (score 1):

I see no real advantage for this as your objects are very small. But for things like dynamically allocated large vectors this could be useful.

One way to implement it is to create a temporary noop class to hold the unevaluated expression. This class would be convertible to Vec so that it becomes transparent to the user. The point is that you can now create an specialized operator= for the add expression. Some code (fill the gaps):

```
struct VecAdd;
struct Vec
{
    Vec& operator=(const VecAdd& vecadd) { /*...*/ }
};

struct VecAdd
{
    const Vec& v1;
    const Vec& v2;
    operator Vec() { return Vec(/*...*/); } // for things like: f(v+u);
};

VecAdd operator+(const Vec& a, const Vec& b) { return VecAdd{a, b}; }
```

This is what GMP actually does. But with a lot of macros and templates to make the code less repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

How about `operator+=` which you then would use as `myVec += otherVec`

Comment: I would like `c = a + b` as well.

Comment: Define both. For bonus marks, define your `operator+` in terms of your `operator+=` like so: `Vec operator+(Vec &rhs) { Vec temp; temp += rhs; return temp; }`

Comment: Makes it incredibly easy to add both, no code duplication, makes your class nice to use... just a good habit to get into in general ;)

Comment: In general if people are able to use `a = a + b` but not `a += b` that's kind of confusing - unless there's a good reason not to have both it just makes your class more intuitive to use.